# nginx proxy_pass directive acting up on OSX?

Tags: nginx, debian, mac-osx

I have the following lines in my `nginx.conf` on my Mac:

```
        location /addPat {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass http://some_url:8080$request_uri;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

Which is directly copied from a machine on the same network running Debian. There is no difference.

But while that directive works perfectly on the Linux box, it constantly returns a 404 on my Mac; and the log entry is this:

```
2014/05/12 17:04:35 [error] 437#0: *13 "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6/html/addPat/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /addPat/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

Which is quite annoying since it just seems inconsistent when you'll expect it work across all platforms.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Probably your request end up in another server block. There is default one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But then I have other paths on the same block, `/mgr/` works perfectly.